# Scrapy throws UnicodeEncode error on some items from the same page

Tags: python, scrapy, amazon-dynamodb

My spider skips some of the items I parse throwing this error. All items are on one page. There are 20 items. Usually, there are 3 or 4 that get skipped. Any suggestions please:

**File "/home/ec2-user/project/project/pipelines.py", line 19, in process_item
    'title': str(item['title']),
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)**

Spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]"):
        url = item.xpath(".//h2/a/@href").extract()[0]
        stamp = item.xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//header/h1/text()").extract_first()
        article['url'] = format(shortener.short(response.url))
        article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
        yield article
```

Pipelines:

class DynamoDBStorePipeline(object):

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="us-west-2")

    table = dynamodb.Table('db1')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
    'url': str(item['url']),
    'title': str(item['title']),
    'stamp': str(item['stamp']),
    }
    )
    return item
```

Comment: It looks like Scrapy is returning Unicode strings and you're converting them to byte strings, why are you doing that? Just leave off the `str`.

Comment: yeah, i just corrected it myself. i changed `'title': str(item['title'])` to `'title': item['title'].encode('utf-8')` and its all fine now

Comment: Yes, but why do you need `encode` in the first place? It would be much better to work with Unicode strings directly, especially if you ever intend to convert to Python 3.

Comment: otherwise, some data doesnt get saved to DynamoDB because it throws encoding error

Answer (score 1):

i changed `'title': str(item['title'])` to `'title': item['title'].encode('utf-8')` and its all fine now